# Resizing and positioning Twitter insight share popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

When popping the twitter "tweet" window it's positioned far to the left of the parent window and has a large amount of space below it. I've dug through the docs and haven't found anything about how to adjust size and position of the window. Any advice or help would be appreciated.

[image]

Load the Twitter SDK source Asynchronously

```
window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
    var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
    js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f); } });
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
```

Click event

```
$('.twitter').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet');

    twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
        alert('tweet');
    });

});
```

Link

```
<a href="#" class="share twitter"></a>
```

Comment: For me it's popping up the Tweet window positioned at the center of my screen.

Comment: Yeah it's not happening in my browsers.